# Mails sent from my domain goes into Spam

Tags: email-validation, email-spam, email-verification, email-bounces, email-analytics

Using a product(email campaigning) i am sending email from my smtp server, that email goes into spam to the recipient.

I had gone for IP reputation, something like checked for blacklisting resulted positively was not blacklisted.

Can any one please suggest me the solution or show me the right path to solve this.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an SPF ([Sender Policy Framework](http://www.openspf.org/)) set up on your domain, you should do that.  It will allow your recipients' mail program to verify that whomever is sending mail through your domain is permitted to do so, thus less likely to be flagged as spam.

Comment: Hi saluce, as said we have specified SPF,but still its occurring.

Comment: Do you have a copy of an email that was sent to spam?  Specifically, the full headers from the email that was received?  Try posting that (blocking out anything you don't want displayed like email address or certain IP addresses) so we can see them and analyze why the email is going to spam.